# Rails 4 - Mysql2::Error: Index column size too large

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, indexing

In rails 4.2.4, I am getting an error like `Mysql2::Error: Index column size too large. The maximum column size is 767 bytes.` while running the migration command.

Mysql gem is,

```
mysql2 (0.3.20, 0.3.18)
```

When I run this `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.collation` in console, then I got the output like `"utf8_general_ci"`

How can I fix this issue? Please help me.

Comment: This may help you https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/9855

Answer (score 2):

The maximum length of a single column index in a innodb table is 767 bytes ([innodb restrictions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-restrictions.html)). Probably you try to index a varchar column with utf8 character set (up to 3 bytes per character) that is longer than 255 characters.

The workaround could be to set [innodb_large_prefix](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_large_prefix) mysql server configuration variable, or reduce the maximum length of that column, or change the character set and collation, or split the column up to multiple columns.